# Retain the cluster number for each member of a cluster within an id variable

Tags: stata

I would like to label how many unique clusters of data are in a longitudinal dataset and have each member of the cluster carry the cluster count. Distinct clusters are those sharing a set of dates within an id. The order of those distinct cluster relative to previous (earlier) clusters creates the desired result. This coding is necessary to address the problem of event ordering required for a time-dependent covariate analysis.

```
input id    date
1   28jan2015
1   28jan2015
2   26nov2015
3   19oct2015
4   26dec2015
5   23dec2015
6   22may2015
6   23sep2015
6   23sep2015
7   14jan2015
7   27feb2015
7   30may2015
8   16apr2015
8   16apr2015
8   16apr2015
8   16apr2015
8   16apr2015
9   17jul2015
9   03oct2015
9   03oct2015
10  27jul2015
end
```

I have attempted:

```
bys id (date): gen count_obs = [_n]
bys id date: gen count_interval_obs = [_n]
egen n_interval = group(id date)
```

resulting in accurate counts of the total number of observations per `id` and enumeration of the number of observations within a `date`. However, the `egen` function `group()` results in identifying each unique set of dates, but numbers the groups without regard to `id`, giving:

```
id  wrong_cluster correct_cluster
1   28jan2015 1 1
1   28jan2015 1 1
2   26nov2015 2 1
3   19oct2015 3 1
4   26dec2015 4 1
5   23dec2015 5 1
6   22may2015 6 1
6   23sep2015 7 2
6   23sep2015 7 2
```

etc.

`egen, group()` cannot be used with the `by:` prefix.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Todd

Edit: Added an explanation of why the cluster identification is necessary. Clarified what rule defines a cluster.

Comment: I find this confusing. What is the rule that leads to the variable `correct_cluster`?

Comment: Apologies, a unique set of dates within an id and the order of that situation relative to previous (earlier) clusters.

Comment: Unique clusters are those occurring just once. A better term here is distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Roberto Ferrer has given a direct approach. It follows from the logic he uses that there is also a route using `egen`'s `group()` function:

```
egen group = group(id date2)
bysort id (group): gen clust2 = sum(group != group[_n-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

For each `id`, when the date is different than the preceding observation, add `1` to the running sum. The `1` is realized when the condition inside `sum()` is met.

```
clear
set more off

input id str15 date
1   28jan2015
1   28jan2015
2   26nov2015
3   19oct2015
4   26dec2015
5   23dec2015
6   22may2015
6   23sep2015
6   23sep2015
7   14jan2015
7   27feb2015
7   30may2015
8   16apr2015
8   16apr2015
8   16apr2015
8   16apr2015
8   16apr2015
9   17jul2015
9   03oct2015
9   03oct2015
10  27jul2015
end

gen date2 = date(date, "DMY")
format %td date2
drop date

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

bysort id (date2) : gen clust = sum(date2 != date2[_n-1])

list, sepby(id)
```